# Application Registration only allows http(s) as Redirect URI

Tags: redirect, callback, soundcloud, custom-protocol

I want to build a desktop application and need the redirect URI to be something like `my-app://soundcloud/callback`. In the application registration form, it's not possible to enter such redirect URI in the input field because only `http` and `https` protocols are allowed. How and where can I set the redirect to be `my-app://soundcloud/callback`?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a website url that would redirect to a custom url. For example, if you want to have the `redirect_uri` to be `myapp://soundcloud/callback`, you could register a domain, and apply with the `redirect_uri` = `http://myapp.domain.com/soundcloud/callback`, and have that url redirect to `myapp://soundcloud/callback` with all of the same headers and parameters.